# Problems using .cab with every installer

Tags: installation, virtualbox, cab

Using several installers, I get errors related to missing .cab files:

> The cabinet file 'product.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used

and

> The cabinet file 'disk1.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used"

I've downloaded the latest [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox), [version 4.2.10](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.10/VirtualBox-4.2.10-84105-Win.exe), and whenever I try to install I get errors. I know the file isn't corrupt because I've downloaded it several times, and it has always failed. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by rebooting the PC. I had the same problem. I think it has to do with some other program, so I rebooted and didn't start anything up until after doing the Visual Basic install. It worked perfectly.