# Bluestacks offline installer installation error

Tags: windows-8, bluestacks

I get this error whenever I try to install using offline installer in my Windows 8 64 bit

> The cabinet file 'product.cab' required for this installation is
>   corrupt and cannot be used. This could indicate a network error, an
>   error reading from the cdrom or a problem with the package.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ICCu69K-Aw

Comment: the video you linked tells to install quick books diagnostic tool. I think it is for installing quickbooks not bluestacks

Comment: yes but it has also got the same error of 1335 as you got.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/569934/problems-using-cab-with-every-installer

Comment: yes but it fixes it with quickbooks diagnostic tool. It is meant only specifically for quickbooks installation. And I also did reboot and tried the installation again. But it shows the same error.